# JS pass default parameter as a variable that is defined inside that function?

Tags: javascript, parameters, default

For example:

```
function mf(z, x c, lol = b) { // I need lol = azazaz
  let b = azazaz
  ...
}
```

Instead of `lol = azazaz` I obviously get `b is not defined`.

What I can do:

```
function mf(z, x, c, lol = "b") { //parameter lol is a string
  let b = azazaz
  lol = eval(lol) //now lol = azazaz
  ...
}
```

Also I can do this:

```
function mf(z, x, c, lol) { //parameter lol doesn't have default value
  b = azazaz
  if (lol == 0) {
    lol = b             //default value of lol = azazaz
  }
  ...
}
```

But the first one looks so non-professional, the second one has extra if statement which I also don't want. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `function mf(z, x c, lol = 'azazaz')` or when you call it like `mf(z, x c, 'azazaz')` ?

Comment: function mf(z, x c, lol = 'b') where 'b' contains the result of some actions inside of my function. The 'b' can be 'azazaz' or another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If defining the variable inside of the function isn't a hard requirement, you can probably leverage closures to do something like:

```
const b = 'azazaz';
function mf(z, x, c, lol = b) { 
 ...
}
```

Or, perhaps use 'OR' to avoid `if`

```
function mf(z, x, c, lol) { //parameter lol doesn't have default value
  let b = 'azazaz';
  lol = lol || b;
  ...
}
```

Comment: `lol = lol || b` could also be written as `lol ||= b`. See the [`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) documentation for details and compatibility.

Comment: @3limin4t0r makes sense, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change paramater and re-use it you must re-call the function like:

```js
//every time function change lol and recall function
function mf(z, x, c, lol) {
  console.log('lol now is: ' + lol);
  lol++;
  if (lol <= 10) {
    mf(1, 2, 3, lol);
  }
}

mf(1, 2, 3, 0);
```